# Create a user in logins during installation with SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

I need to install SQL Server 2019 Express and SSMS on a PC and create another login on SSMS with right click on logins->"Add Login".

I want to know and how, if it's possible, to create a login during installation (with `configuration.ini` for example) or maybe with a request ?

I'd like to create automatically in installation a user like we create a user when we make a right-click on Security->Logins and select "New login". Is it possible or not with SQL Server Express ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible as part of installation. After installation you'll need to connect to the instance and run [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thanks David

I install several softwares with inno setup. I think it's possible to install SQL server Express and the SSMS with inno setup. 

Do you think it's possible to make a request with inno setup to create the login ? (If i can't create it when installing SQL, I hope i can use Inno setup to create login after the SQL installation)
If the login creation could automatic by using inno setup it will be good.